# Why do we sometimes separate behaviour from classes in Java

Tags: java, oop, class, dto

Its a pretty basic question but I am new to Java designing to please excuse me. :)

I want to know in which scenarios we need to separate the class behavior from the class itself.

for e.g.

If I have an class Employee, I will have some data in it like - name, age etc. Also this class will have some behavior like doWork() etc. Now in what scenario we can have data and the behavior inside once class (Employee) only and in which scenario we need to have 2 different classes for Employee data (EmployeeDTO) and behavior (EmployeeService)

Very subjective question but am looking for some inputs on a design of a small application where I am taking data from a text file. Should I put the data and behavior in different classes or same? What will be your reason to justify this decision?

PS: Any links to information on this will also be very useful :)

Thankyou

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the simplest thing possible. You can always make your code more generalized later and there's a good chance you won't even have to do it.

Apply [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) principle every time you need to make a decision. [Extreme Programming wiki](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html) is also a nice reading.

Put everything into one class right now. When you see your Employee is getting too fat then you can do some refactoring - for example, [move method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/moveMethod.html) to another class. In statically typed languages like Java it is super easy because compiler helps a lot and IDE support is great.

Reading from file, for example, looks like an obvious candidate to extract to a separate loader class. On the other hand if you have a very common format as input such as XML or JSON you could just create static method `List<Employee> Employee.loadFromFile(string fileName)` and implement reading logic in a couple of lines of code. It's good enough right now: simple, short and works fine.

May The [Real Ultimate Programming Power](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/real-ultimate-programming-power.html) be with you!

Answer (score 9):

Good object-oriented design advocates that each class obey the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Which I can't summarize any more eloquently than the wikipedia entry:

> Martin defines a responsibility as a reason to change, and concludes
>   that a class or module should have one, and only one, reason to
>   change. As an example, consider a module that compiles and prints a
>   report. Such a module can be changed for two reasons. First, the
>   content of the report can change. Second, the format of the report can
>   change. These two things change for very different causes; one
>   substantive, and one cosmetic. The single responsibility principle
>   says that these two aspects of the problem are really two separate
>   responsibilities, and should therefore be in separate classes or
>   modules. It would be a bad design to couple two things that change for
>   different reasons at different times.

If you think about it, you could jam all of your Java code into one class file, but you don't. Why? Because you want to be able to change, maintain, adapt and test it.  This principle says that instead of dividing your code up arbitrarily into different modules, you should take the tact that things should be broken up by their logical responsibilities. This generally means more, small modules which we know to be easier to change, maintain, adapt and test.

I personally would recommend that you factor your code out into smaller discrete classes and combine them later if this proves to be unreasonable -- this will become obvious to you.  Its much easier to combine loosely-coupled code in the future than it is to factor out tightly-coupled code.

Answer (score 2):

By keeping business logics out of pojo, thus making it a pure transfer object, you have the benefit of loose coupling should one day you find yourself in the situation for the need to switch from Spring framework to EJB JavaBeans.

By putting data and business logic together, it becomes a domain object. The simplest form of managed bean usage promoted in JSF2 uses the domain model whereby the "action" is fused together with form data.

If you choose the first model, you can cleanly separate concerns for designing inheritence and polymorphism for your data objects, while not being bothered if the behaviors defined are making sense, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You use a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (like the acronym suggests) when you want to move data around using the lightest weight way possible, such as over the wire to a service.

Comment: Why does the object become "lighter" if methods are removed? The serialized form does not get smaller, does it?

Comment: You can chose not to have certain fields that are derived, cached, etc. make it as small as possible (but no smaller)

Answer (score 0):

For the record

Its the classic rich domain object vs anemic domain object.

In general, if you have an UI Object or a Library Object (for example the class Date or the class TextButton), and may be some other kind of Objects then may be you can wrap all in a single Class instead of relies in different classes just for commodity to have all the attributes and methods in the same class.

However, for a classic Business Object (BO) is different.   Even if you want a rich domain object, excluding some other problems that i don't want to mention at this point, is the fact that the Business Service (BS) Layer  acts as a "fat burning diet plan" and it turns every rich BO into a anemic BO.

Rich BO -------> BS ----------> Anemic BO.